# java htmlunit throwing ScriptException on Clicking Submit Button of a Page

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
 public HtmlPage getCBSE18(String roll, String schCode, String centerno) throws IOException {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(CBSE18);

        final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("FrontPage_Form1");
        //System.out.println(form.asText());
        final HtmlTextInput regField = form.getInputByName("regno");
        regField.type(roll);

        final HtmlTextInput schField = form.getInputByName("sch");
        schField.type(schCode);

        final HtmlTextInput centerField = form.getInputByName("cno");
        centerField.type(schCode);

        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("B2");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        System.out.println(button.asText());

        final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();

        System.out.println(page2.asText());
        return page2;
```

The above function loads a page from "http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/class12th18.htm" it is a site from where a student can see his results of CBSE 2018 examination .... and fills up the required fields after which it clicks the submit button on  the page ..then it returns the page showing the result of the candidate ...but all i am getting is this exception ...

```
    May 31, 2018 8:55:44 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Submit
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[522] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function routeEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js#522)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function routeEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js#522)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:914)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:599)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:527)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:843)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:815)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:308)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:192)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$2.run(DomElement.java:1420)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:599)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:527)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1425)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.doClickFireClickEvent(DomElement.java:1092)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1023)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:973)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:903)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:884)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:865)
    at resultrobot.html.CBSEResultFetcher.getCBSE18(CBSEResultFetcher.java:89)
    at resultrobot.html.CBSEResultFetcher.main(CBSEResultFetcher.java:128)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function routeEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js#522)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4130)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4108)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4141)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:4160)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4236)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2520)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2502)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1327)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:417)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:325)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:836)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:899)
    ... 21 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function routeEvent in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js#522)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4130)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4108)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4141)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:4160)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4236)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2520)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2502)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1327)
    at script.markClick(http://www.cbseresults.nic.in/class12zpq/cal2.js:522)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:417)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:325)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3424)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:836)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:599)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:527)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:843)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:815)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventHandler(EventListenersContainer.java:308)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:192)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$2.run(DomElement.java:1420)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:599)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:527)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1425)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.doClickFireClickEvent(DomElement.java:1092)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1023)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:973)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:903)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:884)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:865)
    at resultrobot.html.CBSEResultFetcher.getCBSE18(CBSEResultFetcher.java:89)
    at resultrobot.html.CBSEResultFetcher.main(CBSEResultFetcher.java:128)
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
  function markClick(e) {
      if (isIE || isOpera6) {
          winX = event.screenX;
          winY = event.screenY;
      } else {
          if (isN4 || isN6) {
              winX = e.screenX;
              winY = e.screenY;
              document.routeEvent(e);
          }
      }
      if (isN4 || isN6) {
          document.routeEvent(e);
      } else {
          event.cancelBubble = false;
      }
      return true;
  }
======= EXCEPTION END ========
Java Result: 1
```

Finally it worked by
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
its the javascript throwing error

Comment: Please check your browser console if you get the same error when running in real browsers and make sure your are simulating the same browser with hthmunit.

Comment: I have tried all possible browser versions...actually I have tried selenium and it works fine ...but selenium requires chromedriver and lot more stuff ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first time, tell webclient not to throw exception for script error by enabling the option

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```